# Why doesn't the gluon fusion channel for Higgs production diverge?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, renormalization, higgs, regularization

The heavy quark triangle integral has a superficial degree of divergence of $D=1$, so one would *naively* expect it to diverge (more than logarithmically, in fact) in 4 dimensions.

It happens, though, that some cancellation takes place and, in the end of the day, the diagram is finite and gauge-invariant.

This phenomenon (of diagrams with better behaviour than implied by the superficial degree of divergence) is, of course, known to happen, but why is this the case in this specific scenario? Is there a general procedure that could be applied, before calculations, to be sure that this diagram is finite despite its superficial degree of divergence -- and that could also be applied to other loop diagrams?

I have read the argument "*divergences are expected to factorize in lower order perturbative contributions, and since this diagram is the first contribution to $gg \to H$, then we could expect it to be finite*", but I can't make sense of it mathematically.